# Order of three integers

Tags: java

> Given three ints, `a` `b` `c`, and boolean `equalOK` print `"Strictly Increasing Order"` if `a` `b` `c` are in strict increasing order, such as `2 5 11`, or `5 6 7`, but not `6 5 7` or `5 5 7`. However, with the exception that if `"equalOk"` is `true`, equality is allowed, such as `5 5 7` or `5 5 5` print `"Increasing Order"`. Otherwise print `"Not in order"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem8 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();

        boolean equalOK = true;
        equalOK = scan.nextBoolean();

        if(c > b && c > a && b > a)
        {
            System.out.println("Strictly Increasing Order");
        }
        else if((a == b && c > b && equalOK) || (b == c && c > a && equalOK) || (a == b && b == c && equalOK))
        {
            System.out.println("Increasing Order");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not in Order");
        }
    }

}
```

When I submitted this to an online judge it gave me a score of 21/100

What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the difference between `Strictly Increasing Order` and `Increasing Order`?

Comment: I guess what it means that Strictly Increasing Order is when the three integers are different from each other, while Increasing Order is when at least two of them are the same.

Comment: Strictly means, near numbers cannot be equal.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ In strictly increasing, speaking in simple words, no two numbers can be same i.e. no flatness. Whereas increasing allows repeated numbers. In both cases, numbers are increasing order

Comment: Your question looks unclear to me, is `equalOK` driving the result or the order rule is driving the result. Please specify your requirement / rule of the ordering instead of using `equalOK ` ..

Comment: I presume you *copy pasted the requirements* precisely? Note the odd lower/upper case in the desired outputs. Try matching that precisely in your program, maybe the online judge is case sensitive.

Comment: @Durandal THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code is handling correctly every case so the problem must be elsewhere.

Since equality is allowed if `equalOK` is `true`, the condition can be written more simply with:

```
else if(equalOK && c >= b && c >= a && b >= a)
{
    System.out.println("Increasing Order");
}
```

This is the same condition as `"Strictly Increasing Order"` but with equality allowed.

Your code expects the scanner to read the following tokens (for example) `5 5 7 true` so that `a=5`, `b=5`, `c=7` and `equalOK=true`.

Comment: Does this generate a different result from what the OP already has? Or do you mean the judge reduced the score because of the code complexity?

Comment: @Codebender Actually, I rechecked and it seems to be the same (although written more simply). I now think the issue comes from the data that the scanner is reading (not formatted as the OP reads it), hence my edit.

Comment: problem here instead of (b == c && c > a && equalOK) should be (b == c && b > a && equalOK)

Comment: but anyway, this is too dificult code, your code is much better

Comment: @annoirq How can it be? if `b == c` then `c > a == b > a`.

Comment: @Tunaki if b ==c, then c == b > a

Answer (score 0):

This code can be made much simpler :

```
    if(c > b && b > a) {
        System.out.println("Strictly Increasing Order");
    }
    else if (c >= b && b >= a && equalOK)
    {
        System.out.println("Increasing Order");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not in Order");
    }
```

You don't need to check three inequalities, since the `>` relation is transitive (i.e. if c>b and b>a then c>a). And instead of checking equality for `"Increasing Order"`, use `>=`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Though my score is still 21!! I don't understand this!

Comment: @HovigArtinian Perhaps you misunderstood the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use, this code:

```
else if(equalOK && c >= b && b >= a)
{
    System.out.println("Increasing Order");
}
```

The problem in your code instead of:

```
(b == c && c > a && equalOK)
```

use

```
  (b == c && b > a && equalOK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this this condition is enough `(a <= b && c >= b && equalOK)`
You can find the full text afterword

```
 import org.junit.Test;

 import java.util.Random;


 public class Order {


@Test
    public void order()
    {
        int max=4;
        Random r= new Random();
        int a = r.nextInt(max);
        int b = r.nextInt(max);
        int c = r.nextInt(max);
        System.out.println("a ,b ,c "+a +","+b+","+c);

        boolean equalOK = false;

        System.out.println("equal OK "+equalOK);
        checkOrder(a, b, c, equalOK);

        equalOK = true;
        System.out.println("equal OK "+equalOK);
        checkOrder(a, b, c, equalOK);
    }

private void checkOrder(int a, int b, int c, boolean equalOK) {
    if(c > b && b > a)
    {
        System.out.println("Strictly Increasing Order");
    }
    else if((a <= b && c >= b && equalOK))
    {
        System.out.println("Increasing Order");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not in Order");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
 if((a == b && c > b && equalOK) || (b == c && c > a && equalOK) || (a == b && b == c && equalOK))
            {
                System.out.println("Increasing Order");
            }
            else if(c > b && b > a )
            {
                System.out.println("Strictly Increasing Order");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not in Order");
            }
```